# While loop not fully executing and cannot work out why

Tags: python, while-loop

So I am working on a Python project and I am still quite new to Python. I have written the following code:

```
while True:
    try:
        question = int(input("What year was the highest year of recorded cases?"))
    except:
        print("Error. Number required.")
        break
    if {question == '2022'}:
        print("Correct answer.")
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect answer.")
        break
```

But the else statement does not execute and I cannot work out why. Does anyone have any thoughts? The rest of the code seems to work no issue just the else statement section.

I have tried re writing it encase the formatting was off and I tried to add continue or finally clause but this just generated a syntax error.

Comment: Why do you have `{}` around the condition? `{question == '2022'}` is a non-empty set, which will always be true, so the `else` will never execute.

Comment: And as the now-deleted answer says, `question == '2022'` is also comparing the integer `question` against the string `'2022'`, which will never be true, so once you fix the first issue, you'll have the opposite problem.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense I have made the change and its working perfectly so thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add on to what Sreeram said and mention that you are also converting the input to a number, and then comparing it to a string in the if statement. If you remove the quotation marks around '2002', that will give compare the input and 2022 as numbers.

```py
print(2022 == '2022')   # Prints False
print(2022 == 2022)     # Prints True
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the oversight

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are a couple of issues in your code. Let's go through them:

The except block catches any exception, but you only want to catch exceptions related to converting the input to an integer. You should specify the exception you want to catch, which is ValueError in this case.

The condition in the if statement is incorrect. You don't need curly braces around the condition, and you should compare the entered value directly with the integer 2022, not the string '2022'.

The break statement in both the if and else blocks will cause the loop to exit in any case. You probably want to remove the break statements from the else block to allow the loop to continue until the correct answer is provided.

Here's the corrected code:

```
while True:
try:
    question = int(input("What year was the highest year of recorded cases? "))
except ValueError:
    print("Error. Number required.")
    continue  # Continue the loop if an exception occurs
if question == 2022:
    print("Correct answer.")
    break
else:
    print("Incorrect answer.")
```

With these changes, the program should work as expected. It will keep prompting the user for input until they enter a valid integer, and it will correctly check if the entered year is 2022 or not.

Comment: Thank you for your advice will give that a try

Answer (score 0):

It is more pythonic to include an else block if your except block doesn't catch any error. Within that else block, you can then add your if-else blocks. Also, you directly converted user input to int but then used it as a string in your if statement. Also, no need for the curly braces.

I have fixed your code and this works:

```
while True:
    try:
        question = int(input("What year was the highest year of recorded cases? "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Error. Number required.")
        break
    else:
        if question == 2022:
            print("Correct answer.")
            break
        else:
            print("Incorrect answer.")
            break
```